# how to select a single item and get it's relations in faunadb?

Tags: faunadb

I have two collections which have the data in the following format

```
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("Leads"), "267824207030650373"),
  "ts": 1591675917565000,
  "data": {
    "notes": "voicemail ",
    "source": "key-name",
    "name": "Glenn"
  }
}

{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("Sources"), "266777079541924357"),
  "ts": 1590677298970000,
  "data": {
    "key": "key-name",
    "value": "Google Ads"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to query the `Leads` collection and be able to retrieve the corresponding `Sources` document in a single query

I came up with the following query to try and use an index but I couldn't get it to run

```
Let(
      {
        data: Get(Ref(Collection('Leads'), '267824207030650373'))
      },
      {
        data: Select(['data'],Var('data')),
        source: q.Lambda('data',
              Match(Index('LeadSourceByKey'), Get(Select(['source'], Var('data') )) )
            )
      }
)
```

Is there an easy way to retrieve the Sources document ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the following query which I broke down for you in multiple steps:

```js
Let(
  {
    // Get the Lead document 
    lead: Get(Ref(Collection("Leads"), "269038063157510661")),
    // Get the source key out of the lead document
    sourceKey: Select(["data", "source"], Var("lead")),
    // use the index to get the values via match 
    sourceValues: Paginate(Match(Index("LeadSourceValuesByKey"), Var("sourceKey")))
  },
  {
    lead: Var("lead"),
    sourceValues: Var("sourceValues")
  }
)
```

The result is:

```js
{
  lead: {
    ref: Ref(Collection("Leads"), "269038063157510661"),
    ts: 1592833540970000,
    data: {
      notes: "voicemail ",
      source: "key-name",
      name: "Glenn"
    }
  },
  sourceValues: {
    data: [["key-name", "Google Ads"]]
  }
}
```

sourceValues is an array since you specified in your index that there will be two items returned, the key and the value and an index always returns the array. Since your **Match** could have returned multiple values in case it wasn't a one-to-one, this becomes an array of an array.

This is only one approach, you could also make the index return a reference and **Map/Get** to get the actual document as explained on the [forum](https://forums.fauna.com/t/querying-a-one-to-one-relations-using-fql/232/5).

However, I assume you asked the same question [here](https://forums.fauna.com/t/querying-a-one-to-one-relations-using-fql/232/5). Although I applaud asking questions on stackoverflow vs slack or even our own forum, please do not just post the same question everywhere without linking to the others. This makes many people spend a lot of time while the question is already answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You might probably change the Leads document and put the Ref to Sources document in source:

```
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("Leads"), "267824207030650373"),
  "ts": 1591675917565000,
  "data": {
    "notes": "voicemail ",
    "source": Ref(Collection("Sources"), "266777079541924357"),
    "name": "Glenn"
  }
}

{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("Sources"), "266777079541924357"),
  "ts": 1590677298970000,
  "data": {
    "key": "key-name",
    "value": "Google Ads"
  }
}
```

And then query this way:

```
Let(
      {
        lead: Select(['data'],Get(Ref(Collection('Leads'), '267824207030650373'))),
        source:Select(['source'],Var('lead'))
      },
      {
        data: Var('lead'),
        source: Select(['data'],Get(Var('source')))
      }
)
```